# how to select span with specific email attribute value with Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, email, search, css-selectors, puppeteer

using Puppeteer trying to search in my email page for recent emails that contain specific ("email" in my case) attribute or by the text value at least

```html
<span  email="noreply@example.com" name="Moon">Moon</span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using $:

```
const ele = await page.$('span[email="noreply@example.com"]');
```